# Dynamically create views containing buttons - what about constraints?

Tags: objective-c

I want a menu (hidden on the left side of my app) with a variable amount of buttons (depending on the user). I took the app over from another developer and he manually added every view and every button and it is a pain to maintain if you want to add another button in between or change something. So I want to redo it automatically.

But how can I achieve that? Let's say i have on the left x views, each containing an image, a button and a separator (to the button below). So I basically only create one single prototype view, button combo and reuse it for all other buttons. But how do I arrange them so the constraints are correctly set?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would go with a table-view. Setup a cell with an image and a button, separators come for free in a table-view. Make sure the cell has a delegate for the button call-back or a closure to handle the button tap.
Add a controller/manager to control the number of views based on the user.